# How to take screenshot of /dev/pts?

Tags: bash, ssh

I am connecting to another server using ssh service.
I want to execute some commands (like creating users) on some servers and take the screenshot of the pseudo-terminal, which is to be stored on my machine in the format of (*.jpg or *.png).

I have googled it, I have seen lot of programs for gui mode like scrot, capture. I want to take screenshot of the server which have no gui.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a "screenshot"? Can't you just redirect STDOUT and STDERR to a file? (i.e. append `&> /path/to/file`)

Comment: http://www.pc-freak.net/blog/how-to-make-screenshot-in-devtty-console-on-gnu-linux-taking-picture-jpeg-png-snapshot-of-text-console-in-systems-without-graphical-environment/

Answer (score 1):

It is much easier to make a screenshot on your machine, as you want to store the images there anyway. That way you only have to have the capturing software installed there.

If you just want to document the commands you executed you can copy the .bash_history from a machine after login out (using `scp root@server1:~/.bash_history server1_bh.log`).

If you also want the output of the command you should look at a terminal program that lets you easily grab what you have done, or an SSH client that lets you grab a session (e.g. [PuTTY](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.63/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-logging)).

Having the log as a text file makes it more easy to edit out errors like mistyped commands, than it would be in a screenshot.